# why the file object become null after camera capture

Tags: android, file

my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private View TakePhotoBtn;

        private ImageView ProductPhoto;

        private Button ReviewBtn;

        public static File file;

        private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              .....

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
        }

        void TakePhoto() {

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + File.separator + "test.png");
                Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                imageUri);
                BugTrackerApp.app.file =file ;

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {



// this line is getting null value .... why 

                        file =  BugTrackerApp.app.file ;
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                         ProductPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                         ReviewAct.ImageFile = file;

                }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your process was terminated while you were in the background. Do not rely upon static data members for anything more than a cache.

Comment: you mean I could lose some of my static references !

Comment: @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush: "you mean I could lose some of my static references" -- yes. In general, this is perfectly normal, though it is always disappointing when it happens in the flow that you are describing. Any time that you go away from the foreground (HOME, incoming phone call, user responds to a `Notification`, user switches to another app via the recent-tasks list, etc.), your process can be terminated to free up RAM.

Answer (score 0):

what did you do to `BugTrackerApp`? Have you checked it? 
Why do you need the two lines?

```
BugTrackerApp.app.file =file ;
file =  BugTrackerApp.app.file ;
```

You created a file to store captured image, and decoded it in `onActivityResult`. so this line

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + File.separator + "test.png");
```

is enough.

Comment: I don't want to make new again , I want to know the reason of this behavior

Comment: could you explain what BugTrackerApp is? You didn't show anything about it. There must be something happened inside of BugTrackerApp to cause file value null.

Comment: this is just an application object and there is no code in it

Comment: If you have to globally save the file value, you can use SharedPreferences